Asymptotic of incomplete Beta function
Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m \le \log n$.
I want to find the sharp range of $d_{m,n}$ such that there exists constant $c$ $\textbf{independent}$ $\textbf{of}$ $m,n$ and
$$
\frac{1}{c}\,\mbox{B}(m,n) \le \int_0^{d_{m,n}} u^{m-1} (1-u)^{n-1} \, du \le  c \,\mbox{B}(m,n),
$$
I particularly care the case $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Recall that
$$
\mbox{B}(m,n) = \int_0^1 u^{m-1} (1-u)^{n-1}\, du = \frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}.
$$
I think there must be some reference but I failed to find a suitable one. And I guess $d_{m,n} \ge e^{ m}n^{-1}$ is the sharp range.

I am not sure if it helps but $$
\int_0^{d_{m,n} } {u^{m - 1} (1 - u)^{n - 1} {\rm d}u}  = \frac{1}{{m^n }}\Gamma (n, - m\log d_{m,n} )\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}!\left( {\frac{1}{m}} \right)} \right)
$$ according to this paper.

@Gary Is that uniform in both $m,n$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Unfortunately, it is not. However, it seems to me that $d_{m,n}\ge m/n$. With $=m/n$, $c\approx 2$ works in the lower bound.

Indeed, the median of the beta distribution is $\approx \frac{{m - 1/3}}{{n + m - 2/3}} \approx \frac{m}{n}$.

@Gary The lower bound is enough for me, how do you show that?

The median $\mathbf{m}$ of the beta distribution satisfies the equation
$$
\int_0^{\bf m} {u^{m - 1} (1 - u)^{n - 1} \mathrm{d}u}  = \frac{1}{2}B(m,n).
$$
For $1 < m < n$, the median is bounded by the mode and the mean:
$$
\frac{{m - 1}}{{m + n - 2}} \le {\bf m} \le \frac{m}{{m + n}}.
$$
(cf. this paper). Thus, if $d_{m,n}  \ge \frac{{m - 1}}{{m + n - 2}}$, then
$$
\frac{1}{2}B(m,n) \le \int_0^{d_{m,n} } {u^{m - 1} (1 - u)^{n - 1} \mathrm{d}u}  \le B(m,n).
$$
A weaker, yet simpler, condition for these inequalities to hold is $d_{m,n}  \ge \frac{m}{n}$.

Thanks, it may take some time to check the condition for beta distribution

I've checked it, that's right.
